# ¿Cómo puedo mantener la clase active del parent('li') de un a href del sidebar al momento de agregar un nuevo registro?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como puedo dejar con la clase active un elemento `'li'` del sidebar menú.

El problema que tengo es que cuando selecciono un elemento del menú sí se le agrega  la clase `'current-page'` y se mantiene desplegado el menú.

Hasta ahí todo bien. Pero cuando quiero agregar un nuevo registro sobre esa misma pagina, se recarga de nuevo la pagina y el elemento `'li'` que había seleccionado pierde la clase `'current-page'`, regresando a su estado normal, y el menú se colapsa.

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
// check active menu
$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a[href="' + CURRENT_URL + '"]').parent('li').addClass('current-page');

$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == CURRENT_URL;
}).parent('li').addClass('current-page').parents('ul').slideDown(function() {
    setContentHeight();
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Ya he buscado cómo resolverlo pero no he tenido éxito.

Comment: agrega un identificador unico a los elementos li, y almacena la id con el estado activo en localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Como lo mencione en los comentarios aquí tienes un ejemplo básico y aqui el [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b2up5sL/1/) donde lo puedes probar

```js
if(localStorage.getItem("activo") != undefined){
 let target = localStorage.getItem("activo");
  $('#'+JSON.parse(target).id).addClass('active')
}
$('#listItems > li').on('click',(e)=>{
let target = e.target;
$('#listItems > li').each((i,el)=>{
$(el).removeClass('active');
})
$(target).addClass('active');
var json = {id:$(target).prop("id")};
localStorage.setItem("activo",JSON.stringify(json));
})
```

```css
.active{
  background: red;
}

.inactive{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listItems">
  <li id="1">Prueba 1</li>
  <li id="2">Prueba 2</li>
  <li id="3">Prueba 3</li>
  <li id="4">Prueba 4</li>
</ul>
```

Saludos